# Globally register a directive in angular2 final

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I have some custom directive which i need to use in whole application. How to register my directives to use in whole application? Other questions I came across are all outdated. I need solution for angular 2 final version 2.1.0

my `main.ts` looks like this

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

//enableProdMode(); //Uncomment for production
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .then((success: any) => console.log('App bootstrapped'))
    .catch((err: any) => console.error(err));
```

My app have 6 modules to use lazy oading

```
appmodule 
--contact module
--project module
--restmodules
...
```

When I registered the directive in product module, it worked well. So I used this directive in my rest of modules for which I registered this directive in `appmodule.ts` like this

```
import { mdinput} from './shared/mdinput.directive';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
               AppRoutingModule

    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,mdinput

    ],
    providers: [DataService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

now this particular directive is not working. Nor is it giving any errors.

Comment: Just add it to the declarations of your NgModule. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

Comment: @JBNizet  but its not working diffrent modules

Comment: Don't let us guess what you're trying to achieve. Edit your question, and post all the relevant information about your directive, your modules, etc. You probably need to add it to the exports, too, but without seeing anything, it's hard to guess.

Answer (score 5):

First, create Directive in a separate directory. Let's say you created directive: myHighlight.directive.ts in customDirectives dir. Now

```
import { HighlightDirective } from 'yourpath/customDirectives/myHighlight.directive';
```

and

```
declarations: [..., HighlightDirective]
```

add these in **app.module.ts**.

Now use this in any component view:

```
<td  myHighlight>{{user.name | capitalize}}</td>
```

How this will work.

Answer (score 2):

Just add it to a feature module and add the feature module to `imports: [...]` of the module where you want to use it.

Even `*ngIf`, `*ngFor`, ... now need to be added this way by adding `CommonModule` or `BrowserModule` to `imports`.

For more details see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html